# How to solve try-with-resources error for CSVReader using Java 6

Tags: java, java-6, opencsv, try-with-resources

I am forced to build the JAR file with JDK 6 because it will be used on a company laptop and the laptop owner cannot update their Java version without the laptop going through the IT people.

So, how to work around the try-with-resources error for this method:

```
public static String importFile(String filepath){
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO SALESMAN VALUES (?,?)";
    String status;

    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath), ','); //error here
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();){
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        String[] rowData = null;

        int i = 0;
        while((rowData = reader.readNext()) != null){
            for (String data : rowData){
                pstmt.setString((i % 2) + 1, data);
                if (++i % 2 == 0)
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                if (i % 20 == 0)
                    pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        status = "Successfully uploaded";
    }   catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;        
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The try-with-resource syntax was only introduced in Java 7. If you're forced to use Java 6, you'd have to resort to a good old fashioned `finally` clause:

```
CSVReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath), ',');
    // Code from the original try block, removed for brevity's sake
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // Or some useful error handling
} finally { // closing the reader in the finally block
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the situation when 'CSVReader' constructor throws an exception? This leaves you with an unclosed 'FileReader' object...

Comment: @Grogi this wasn't handled in the OP either, so I didn't address it. Generally speaking, you should have all the resource-referencing variables declared **outside** the `try` block, initialize them **inside** it and close them in the `finally` block, in reverse order to the order they were initialized in.